# R-linear functions

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

Assume that $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C} $ is a $\mathbb{R}$-linear function.

I have read that the equality $ f\left(z\right)=cz+d\overline{z} $ must hold for some $c,d \in \mathbb{C} $.

Why is it true?

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1650324/42969 or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3331261/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Indeed helpful, Thanks

Comment: Given $a,b\in\Bbb C$ there exist $c,d$ so $ax+by=cz+d\overline z$.